# Sharepoint 2013 Development Boundaries

Tags: 2013, rest, client-object-model

I need some understanding around SharePoint 2013 Development model.

What are SharePoint 2013 Development Boundaries?

What SharePoint developer can and cant do with each model?

Comment: Make sure you've read this on limits and boundaries as well: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Looks like your question body doesn't fully disclose your intentions and only tags hint at that you want to *compare REST and CSOM*. Is this correct?

Answer (score 7):

**Farm Solutions (Full Trust):** Develop for SharePoint On-Premises only. Can use managed code and the Server Object Model. This model has been around since SharePoint 2007 and is currently the most robust and well documented.

**Sandbox Solutions:** Develop for SharePoint On-Premises or SharePoint Online. Can currently use managed code and a limited version of the Server Object Model, however this will not be the case moving forward. At some point in the future Sandbox Solutions will not be able to use managed code, they will be limited to the use of HTML, XML (CAML), and JavaScript.

**SharePoint-Hosted Apps:** Develop for SharePoint On-Premises or SharePoint Online. Limited to the use of HTML, XML (CAML), and JavaScript.

**Provider-Hosted Apps:** Develop for SharePoint On-Premises or SharePoint Online. These apps can use managed code but they cannot use the Server Object Model. All communication with SharePoint must be done via the Client Object Model or the REST API.

Comment: Great summary. I would just add. Do not use sandbox solutions - not recommended anymore and probably will not be available in next versions of SP. Try to avoid farm solutions in the future (if possible), because there will be a time when we will be forced to go online and is good to keep this on mind. SharePoint-hosted or Provider-Hosted - decide whether you need to store some additional information outside SP, or do some calculations, operations on the server side. Otherwise it is a good idea to spread the load across the clients.

Comment: Sandbox solutions are *not* being removed from SharePoint. It's only the ability to use managed code inside a sandbox solution that is being removed. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2014/01/14/deprecation-of-custom-code-in-sandboxed-solutions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint comes with two flavors

1. On Premise - The server is installed and maintained by each organization. Developers has Full Control to do major tasks like Deploying Farm solution, Starting Search Crawls etc.
2. Online - Microsoft manages the cloud version. You have minimal options to get things done.

From Developers point of view, [SharePoint offers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163085(v=office.15).aspx)

1. Apps for SharePoint

   An app for SharePoint is similar to an app on a mobile device. It is a stand-alone productivity solution that does a small number of related tasks, installs easily, and uninstalls cleanly. Users can discover and download apps for SharePoint from a public SharePoint app store or from their organization's corporate app catalog. An app for SharePoint can include classic SharePoint components such as lists, custom website pages, Web Parts, workflows, and content types. But an app for SharePoint can also surface a remote web application and remote data in SharePoint. An app for SharePoint can also include both SharePoint and remote components. Apps for SharePoint are very safe applications whose custom logic is always shifted "up" to the cloud or "down" to the client computers. It never runs on the SharePoint servers.
2. SharePoint publishing sites

   SharePoint publishing sites provide large-scale content publishing with a high degree of maintainability and regulation compliance. They also provide management of documents, records, taxonomy, and content types.
3. SharePoint farm solutions

   SharePoint farm solutions are trusted SharePoint extensions whose custom logic calls the SharePoint server object model and runs with full trust on the SharePoint servers. These solutions are primarily for custom administrative extensions of SharePoint, such as timer jobs, custom Windows PowerShell commands, and extensions of Central Administration. Farm solutions are distributed as SharePoint solution packages that farm administrators upload to a farm-wide storage location from which they can be deployed. Components in farm solutions can have farm, web application, site collection, or website scope.
4. Mobile apps for SharePoint

   Windows Phone apps, and apps built on non-Microsoft mobile platforms, can access SharePoint websites and data. Tools for building Windows Phone apps that interact with SharePoint 2013 are available for installation on Visual Studio 2010 (not Visual Studio 2012 at this time). A SharePoint client managed API just for use on Windows Phone devices is available. Mobile devices, including non-Microsoft devices, can also access SharePoint data through SharePoint REST/OData endpoints.
5. Reusable components for SharePoint

   The SharePoint 2013 platform and Visual Studio 2012 enable encapsulation and reuse of application elements, including elements created with code, script, and XML markup.